# Get contract information from transaction information?

Tags: solidity, web3js, blockchain, etherscan

This might be a simple question. Let's say I have the transaction hash:

```
{
  blockNumber: "6214286",
  timeStamp: "1535248365",
  hash: "0x144018f7327b3990124762d1aefececff3897755ce15313e662f2c5699aaaca1",
  nonce: "5",
  blockHash: "0x6bd409190b38364611b96006ead9f2281262e8d4b71cd712e528c7459d56962f",
  transactionIndex: "135",
  from: "0x446252b54d626cf4192e5c74545761dfaf7e5a50",
  to: "0xb1690c08e213a35ed9bab7b318de14420fb57d8c",
  value: "2000000000000000",
  gas: "148770",
  gasPrice: "1400000000",
  isError: "1",
  txreceipt_status: "0",
  input: "0x454a2ab300000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000d1596",
  contractAddress: "",
  cumulativeGasUsed: "4423724",
  gasUsed: "22540",
  confirmations: "189517"
}
```

Is there a way to get what contract function was called with which parameters?

I do have the contract ABI and address.

---

More information:

I have trying to get the CryptoKitty tokenId from the above transaction. I go this transaction by querying Etherscan with my Account and filter on "to" destination that maps to CryptoKitty auction contract (CryptoKittiesSalesAuction).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.

The info you need is here:
 `input: "0x454a2ab300000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000d1596",`

First 4 bytes is what you need to find the function that was called. It is called METHOD ID. You have an example [here](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.25/abi-spec.html?highlight=function#examples)

> This is derived as the first 4 bytes of the Keccak hash of the ASCII form of the signature

And the parameter is `00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000d1596`

In your smart contract, you can find the method id by using **.selector**

for example, for this setup() function, `function setup() external onlyOwner`,
you get method id by doing this: **this.setup.selector**

Answer (score 0):

Try ethereum abi decoder
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ethereum-input-data-decoder
You can decode input data using it.